# Syntax error (when there appears to be none!)

Tags: php, mysql, syntax, foreach, eval

I have spent an hour or so attempting to figure out this one error.. It looks right to me, but I am by far no expert. So I thought I would ask the experts! I keep getting this error:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '' (T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE), expecting identifier (T_STRING) or variable (T_VARIABLE) or number (T_NUM_STRING) in ... on line 29

from this line of code:

```
eval("$var_value = $_REQUEST['{$value}']");
```

Here is the code around it..

```
function save_edits($var_name, $var_value)
{
    eval("{$var_name} = sql_safe({$var_value});");
    eval("mysql_query(\"UPDATE settings set {$var_name}='{$var_value}' where variable='{$var_name}'\") or die(mysql_error());");
}     
foreach ($_REQUEST as $key => $value)
{
    eval("$var_value = $_REQUEST['{$value}']");
    save_edits($value, $var_value);
}
```

Comment: why are you escaping the last single quote (after key)?

Comment: How is that NOT a syntax error?

Comment: And why is *everything* written using `eval`? There is absolutely no reason to use it here. Do you just enjoy meta-programming?

Comment: I am attempting to make a dynamic setting page. It pulls all variables from mysql and inserts the variables into the enviroment. But I want it all to be dynamic. Like I say, I am no expert, I do not know of any other way.

Comment: Variables are by their very nature dynamic. I have yet to see a use case for eval that could not be achieved using some other means. This is not an exception.

Comment: Variable variables or `extract()` if you have to. Not `eval`!

Comment: @deceze ...or, just stop using all these awful constructs and use a damn array. Job done.

Comment: @alexander7567 Listen to the man. ^

Comment: Ok, I will look into replacing the eval's with arrays. I am open for advice as to how... But I will start looking into it.

Comment: Took @Brad Christie advice.. Works great!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

missing a `]` is appears:

```
eval("$var_value = $_REQUEST['{$key}\'");
                                     ^^
```

Also missing a `)`:

```
eval("{$var_name} = sql_safe({$var_value};");
                                        ^^
```

However, you should **avoid `eval` at much cost**, especially with `$_REQUEST`s (implying user input). As it stands, this query would be harmful to your site:

```
http://your-site.com/?foo='];exec('rm%20*.*');
```

So how about a refactor:

```
function save_edits($var_name, $var_value)
{
    $clean_name = mysql_real_escape_string($var_name);
    $clean_value = mysql_real_escape_string($var_value);
    $sql = "UPDATE settings "
        .= "SET    value = '{$clean_value}' "
        .= "WHERE  variable = '{$clean_name}'";
    mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
}     
foreach ($_REQUEST as $key => $value)
{
    save_edits($key, $value);
}
```

However you should really look in to using:

```
CREATE TABLE settings
(
  id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  name VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
  value VARCHAR(255)
);
```

Then you can sanitize both the name and the value field. You also probably want to look in to using [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) to prevent exploits better.

Comment: Wow.. can't believe i didn't see that.. But that was not my problem. I have updated the post with the new results...

Comment: p.s. Consider using [arrays](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php) or [variable variables](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php) if absolutely necessary.

Comment: That didn't fix it either.. Still have the same error.

Comment: Yes, I may change it to arrays. That would look better. Thanks for the tip!

Comment: This is exactly what I needed.. I just have not thought of doing it that way. That's why i brought it to the experts. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The biggest problem is that you are producing nonsense code with your `eval` string evaluation. Try:

```
echo "$var_value = $_REQUEST['{$value}']";
```

See how the variables in that string get interpolated and what the result is. *That* is what is attempted to be `eval`d and what's producing the syntax error.

Overall, again: that's the most horrible code I've seen in a while. Forget about it. Forget `eval` exists. Throw it away. Start from scratch.